# Passing specific inputs to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm not quite sure how to pass the variables 'item1' and 'item2' to the add function.

```
def main():
    list1 = []
    add(list1)



def inputs():
    item1 = input('Please enter your first item')
    item2 = input('Please enter your second item')

def add(a)
    a.append(item1,item2)
```

Comment: You probably first need to *return* them from your `inputs` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing item1 and item2 in add(a) as if they were global variables, when in fact they are local variables in the namespaces of add(a).

You can either:

declare item1 and item2 above main somewhere as globals, and then define them as
`global item1` `global item2` in all the functions you want to use them,

or

You can have inputs `return (item1,item2)`, and call that function in add(a) and utilize those returned values.

Example 1:

```py
item1 = None
item2 = None

def main():
    list1 = []
    add(list1)


def inputs():
    global item1
    global item2
    item1 = input('Please enter your first item')
    item2 = input('Please enter your second item')

def add(a)
    inputs()
    a.append(item1,item2)
```

Example 2

```py
def main():
    list1 = []
    add(list1)


def inputs():
    item1 = input('Please enter your first item')
    item2 = input('Please enter your second item')
    return (item1, item2)    


def add(a)
    items = inputs()
    a.append(items[0],items[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to maintain the functions you've got, you'd need to return the values.

```
def foo():
    x = input()
    return x

value = foo()
```

However, if all you're trying to do is add some numbers, your code can be dramatically simplified like so:

```
def main():
    n1 = float(input('Please enter your first item'))  # float() converts the string inputs to decimal numbers you can perform maths on
    n2 = float(input('Please enter your second item'))
    total = sum([n1, n2])
```